# firestore getting null even if there is data js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a form and on submit I add a doc with the data to my firestore database.
I have a realtime listener on the collection I add the doc to.

```
onSubmit={async(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        const form = document.querySelector(".activityForm")
                        const colRef = collection(db, "inactivity")

                        await addDoc(colRef, {
                            name: user.displayName,
                            from: form.from.value,
                            to: form.to.value,
                            reason: form.reason.value.trim(),
                            reported: serverTimestamp()
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Success!")
                            form.reset()
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err)
                        })
                        const q = query(colRef, orderBy("reported", "desc") );
                        
                        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
                            setInactiveReps([])
                            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                setInactiveReps(prev => {
                                    return [...prev, doc.data()]
                                    })
                            })
                        });
                    }
```

After, I am trying to map through and display all the docs in the collection.

```
                                {inactiveReps && inactiveReps.map(report => (

                                    date = formatDistance(
                                        new Date(report.reported.seconds*1000),
                                        new Date(),
                                        { 
                                          addSuffix: true,
                                          includeSeconds: true
                                        }
                                      ),
                                      console.log(report),

                                    <tr key={report.id} className="h-auto">
                                        <td className="text-white pl-[21px]">{report.name}</td>
                                        <td className="text-white pl-[21px]">{report.from}</td>
                                        <td className="text-white pl-[21px]">{report.to}</td>
                                        <td className="text-white pl-[21px]">{report.reason}</td>
                                        <td className="text-white pl-[21px]">{date}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))
                            }
```

It worked fine.. until I added the realtime listener. Now I get the following error:
`TypeError: can't access property "seconds", report.reported is null`, when its clearly not null, if I log the doc its shown there:

```
..​.
reported: Object { seconds: 1664099305, nanoseconds: 349000000 }
​...
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but the problem most probably comes from the fact that `serverTimestamp()` "includes a server-generated timestamp in the written data".

So at the moment you execute the `addDoc()` method in your front end, the value of the `reported` field **is not set in your front-end** because it is the server/back-end that sets it. But, due to the ["latency compensation"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes), your listeners will be notified with the new data **before the data is sent to the backend**, resulting to the fact that `report.reported` is `null`.

You therefore need to indicate to the listener set with `onSnapshot()` that it has to only treat events coming from the server/back-end. This can be done with [`metadata.hasPendingWrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.snapshotmetadata.md#snapshotmetadatahaspendingwrites) as follows (untested):

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    setInactiveReps([])
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        if (doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
          // Do whatever you want: skip the doc or add a "pending" value for the timestamp
        } else {
            setInactiveReps(prev => {
                     return [...prev, doc.data()]
            })
        }  
    })
});
```